# Why is norm(x, type='2')!=x%*%x?

Tags: r

Title says it all.

```
x = c(1,2,3)
print(norm(x, type='2')-x%*%x)
```

Prints: -10.25834

Why are they not equal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the 2-norm is the square root of `t(x) %*% x`:

```
> print(norm(x, type='2')^2-x%*%x)
     [,1]
[1,]    0
```